# Problema con bucle while(true) y repaint: No me pinta a ventana del JFrame

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy haciendo un juego de movimiento de una bola. El problema me reside cuando quiero que esta bola se mueva.

Para hacer el movimiento hago un **while(true)** para que el bucle sea infinito y me pinte la bola pareciendo que está en movimiento.

Entonces el error me aparece en este momento, cuando pongo el bucle [while](/questions/tagged/while). Al compilar, no me sale la ventana.

Aqui mi clase ventana que me ejecuta todo lo gráfico:

```
public class Ventana extends JFrame {

//JPanel
private JPanel jpPrincipal; /
private JPanel jpOpciones;
private JPanel jpGraficos;


Circulo circulo = new Circulo();

public Finestra() throws InterruptedException {

    setSize(1100, 600); 
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Bola en movimiento");
    componentesPrincipales();
}

public void componentesPrincipales() throws InterruptedException {

    jpPrincipal = new JPanel(); 
    jpPrincipal.setLayout(null); 

    this.getContentPane().add(jpPrincipal); 
    jpPrincipal.setVisible(true);  
    componentesGraficos();
    while(true){
        repaint();
        circulo.moverBola();
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
}

public void componentesGraficos(){

    jpGraficos = new JPanel();
    jpGraficos.setBounds(10, 10,700,550);
    jpGraficos.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    jpGraficos.setVisible(true);
    jpPrincipal.add(jpGraficos);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    circulo.pintarBola(g2d);  
}
```

Aquí mi clase Circulo, representa la Bola. Viene definida por unas [coordenadas](/questions/tagged/coordenadas) (X y Y) y un [diametro](/questions/tagged/diametro):

```
public class Circulo {

//ATRIBUTOS

private final static int diametro = 30;

//Coordenadas de la posición actual
private int x;
private int y;

public Circulo() {

}

public void moverBola(){
    x = x + 1;
    y = y + 1;
}

public void pintarBolla(Graphics g){
    g.fillOval(200, 200, diametro, diametro);
}
```

Y aqui el Main del programa:

```
public class simulacionMovimento {


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Ventana v = new Ventana();
    v.setVisible(true);

}
```

He ejecutado el código dentro del bucle con un contador para ver si entra en él (no vaya a ser que no llegue al bucle) y el contador si que marcha, ya que hacía que me imprimiera por pantalla. Por lo tanto, entrar en el bucle **while(true)** si que entra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tenia es que estaba ejecutando el *repaint* en el metodo deonde creaba el JPanel con los componentes.

Mi solucion ha sido hacer el bucle *while* a parte, en otro método. Quedando así: `

```
public void Update() throws InterruptedException {

    while (true) {
        cercle.moureBolla();
        repaint();
        Thread.sleep(110);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si colocas dentro de un ciclo While(true) la condición para que el ciclo se siga ejecutando seguirá siendo cierta y se ejecutara siempre, nunca dejara de ejecutarse, también dentro del ciclo pones que se ejecute en un intervalo de (10) milisegundos, en teoría como la pelota se mueve una unidad en x y una en y cada 10 milisegundos.

y considerando el tamaño de la ventana debería verse el movimiento de la pelota aunque sea en un parpadeo... pero nisiquiera eso, sin embargo yo no veo que en ninguna parte estés ejecutando la función paint, ¿La estas ejecutando acaso en algún otro pedazo del código que no pusiste?, si es así muevela al bucle while(true) y ejecútala desde ahí después de que mueves la bola.

Si tampoco funciona así, imagino que la otra opción es que el bucle no este respetando la instrucción sleep(), (y esto tendría bastante sentido si fuese así), ya que movería la pelota tan rápido que nunca la verías en realidad en el programa, no solo eso, si no que no le dices a la pelota que se detenga o que cambie su dirección en algún punto así que obviamente se saldría de los limites y el programa no la podría mostrar despues de un tiempo.

Veo de hecho que el código original era en italiano.

Tienes algunos errores en el código que pusiste como pregunta:

```
public class Ventana extends JFrame
```

la clase se llama **Ventana** el constructor por lo tanto debe tener el mismo nombre que su clase:

```
//Finestra != Ventana, cambia Finestra por Ventana
public Finestra() throws InterruptedException {

     setSize(1100, 600); 
     setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     setTitle("Bola en movimiento");
     componentesPrincipales();

}
```

En la clase circulo, tu función pintarBola la escribiste mal:

```
public void pintarBolla(Graphics g){

     g.fillOval(200, 200, diametro, diametro);

}
```

Cambia pintarBolla por pintarBola.

Por ultimo, en tu clase principal llamada simulacionMovimiento, creas un objeto de tipo Ventana, vale hasta ahí todo bien, pero... ¿Porque nunca llamas a la función componentes principales?, no puedes abrir una ventana si no le haz dicho ni que se configure ni que se abra, lo otro es que setVisible() no lo requieres, ya que ya lo pusiste en tu metodo componentesGraficos() de tu clase Ventana:

```
public class simulacionMovimento {    

     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

         Ventana v = new Ventana();
         //Aquí debajo iniciamos las configuraciones para que arranque la ventana
         v.componentesPrincipales();
         v.setVisible(true);//ESTO NO HACE FALTA quitalo porfavor

     }
}
```

Ah falta una ultima cosa y no menos importante:

En tu clase Circulo tienes dos variables esta x y esta y, ambas no han sido inicializadas por lo tanto tienen como valor por default null, esto daría problemas al programa para hacer lo que luego haces en el metodo moverBola de la clase circulo, ya que si le sumas a null un entero, el resultado sigue siendo null, o si no estoy mal también podrías obtener un error de tipo nullPointerException o de Lang.Math.AritmeticalException (Algo así), no recuerdo muy bien como se escribe el segundo error, para solucionar este error debes añadirle a las variables X y Y un valor inicial en tu caso un entero (Yo usaria 0 para contemplar la pelota moviéndose desde la esquina superior izquierda de la pantalla hasta la esquina inferior derecha de la ventana).

estas variables las inicializaria en el constructor de la clase Circulo:

```
public Circulo{

     this.x = 0;
     this.y = 0;

}
```

intenta estos cambios y mira si funcióna ;)

Comment: Hola @Riven, llamo mi funicion "ComponentesPrincipales" en el constructor de la ventana, por eso solo llamo a la ventana en el main.

Y si, tengo un método Paint, está en el código que he puesto.

Por último, tenías razón, las coordenadas no las tengo inicializadas !

Comment: PD: El codigo esta en catalan, no italiano. Lo traduzco para que así más gente pueda ayudarme! :)

Comment: Yo tengo una idea del porque podría no estar funcionando @Don_Pedro, creo que es porque al entrar en el ciclo while(true), este esta ignorando el comportamiento que intentas añadirle al usar la función sleep() o ya de por si el programa se queda estancado por demasiadas iteraciones consecutivas en un lapso muy corto de tiempo, el resultado de esto es evidente, las coordenadas cambian tan rapido que no te da tiempo de ver la pelota moverse. intenta mirar las coordenadas de la pelota al ejecutar el programa (Si se te ejecuta).

Comment: ya que me dices que por algún error no logras que la ventana abrá?

Comment: Si las coordenadas cambian exageradamente rapido, entonces es posible que el ciclo while(true) este ignorando la función sleep y derive a un error que en javascript se conoce como maximum Call Stack Exceeded.

Comment: Ya lo he arreglado, no me hacia caso de mi bucle, y haciendo un metodo aparte con solo el bucle, me ha permitido llevar a cabo la visualicazión del programa

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema tiene que ver con que los componentes swing solo se actualizan en el hilo de eventos (EventThread).  Por lo que veo creo que no estás llegando a éste.

Yo probaría este cambio :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Ventana v = new Ventana();
             v.setVisible(true);
             v.iniciaReloj();
        }
    });

 }
```

Hasta aquí ya sabemos que lanzamos la ventana en el EventThread.
Ahora, el ciclo que tienes dudo que lo muestre, porque no hay un evento de por medio.
Yo usaría un javax.swing.Timer que genere movimientos cada x milisegundos, y al escuchar los eventos que genere el Timer entonces estaría seguro que se mostrarían.

```
//hacemos que Ventana implemente ActionListener para que escuche reloj (Timer)
public class Ventana extends JFrame implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {

private void iniciaReloj() {
   long retrazo = 10; // milisegundos entre cada evento
   javax.swing.Timer reloj = new javax.swing.Timer(retrazo, this);
   reloj.start();
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent eventoDeReloj) {
    repaint();
    circulo.moverBola();
   /// Thread.sleep(10);   Este ya no se requiere!!!
}

}
```

Obviamente hay que quitar el ciclo (while) que tienes en el método componentesPrinicipales()

Comment: Hola @AlbertoLopez y gracias por tu respuesta. Lo he probado así como me has dicho y no me funciona.. no se ve la pelota.